# Can't navigate back to removed page

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a jQuery Mobile app with two pages.  The first navigates to the second.  When navigating back to the first one from the second, I want to remove the second page from the DOM.  I do this with this code:

```
$(document).on("pagecontainerbeforechange", function (e, data) {
    if (typeof data.toPage !== "string" && data.options.direction == "back") {
        // Remove the previous page
        data.prevPage.remove();
    }
});
```

But then when I attempt to navigate to the second page again, nothing happens.  The pagecreate event for that second page is never raised either.

I have a repro at http://jsfiddle.net/thalman/t6mfxj2f/13/.

Comment: Page is totally removed from DOM. Clone it before hand and then add it back http://jsfiddle.net/2z1nLo9L/

Comment: That still keeps the state of the second page as it was at the time the user navigated back to the first page.  What I really want is for the second page to be created from scratch on the second navigation, just as it was the first time.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2z1nLo9L/1/ now?

Comment: No, that doesn't get me what I want either.  The saved element that's added back into the DOM has the modifications made to it by jQuery Mobile.  It's not the original "fresh" definition.  I think I'm going to change things up with how I'm doing things.  Rather than statically defining the page in the body element, I'm going to dynamically create the page when it's about to be navigated to, and remove it on back navigation.  That will always leave me with a fresh page on each forward navigation.

Comment: I forgot to `.clone()` page. Only modification is `secondPage = $("#secondPage").clone();`